# How to solve error 400(OAuth_error) while integrating google+ login with our website?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing following error while i am integrating the google+ api with my website:

400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_request

Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Raw IP addresses not allowed: http://18.220.156.1/googlelogin

Comment: Gadgujar Check this link https://www.codexworld.com/login-with-google-api-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an IP address. It tells you that in the error message. Use the domain.

If you don't have a domain, maybe set up a dynamic DNS?

Comment: Check on the google side you didn't add the IP instead of the domain either

Comment: According to google, you  are still sending the IP. I just tried it myself! (although the url was `/googlelogin`, not `/google`

Comment: blissed delboy1978uk that you are providing help but ...after providing the public DNS of my instance in place of public Ip the same error is coming...please can you tell me how to intigrate the google login with my website.

Comment: can you provide your emailid... becouse i am creating the button of login with google and that contains many files along with database .... it will be a great help

Comment: you shouldn't need it. We however on SO need to see your code. Again, Google still say you are passing an IP and not a domain

Comment: <?php
session_start();

//Include Google client library
include_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
include_once 'src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';

/*
 * Configuration and setup Google API
 */
$clientId = '634866918472-6lche1p5pgibqaovc3n8i.apps.googleusercontent.com'; //Google client ID
$clientSecret = 'n6Vufaah7BgFr'; //Google client secret
//$redirectURL = 'http://www.palaklun.tk/googlelogin/';

Comment: @PalakBadgujar: You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50681308/edit) rather than putting code in a comment where it will be mostly inaccessible and hard to do anything with.

Comment: have you just pasted your client secret in public?! edit that comment before someone hijacks your client!!!